# Crafty.js not showing correct response using CoffeeScript

Tags: javascript, html, coffeescript, craftyjs

I'm using `Crafty.js`, I recently added a button that is meant to show help info, the button works fine, and I get the return from the server correctly, but I keep getting errors.

It'll be long to explain, so be patient.

This is my code:

```
where = this._current
auxiliary = $.getJSON('/help/', {'scene': where})

Crafty.e("HTML")
.attr({x: 100, y: 200, w: 224, h: 200})
.replace """
  <font color="white">
    #{auxiliary.message}
  </font>
   """
```

When the code is like that, what it shows is: `undefined`, but, if I change the code like:

```
Crafty.e("HTML")
.attr({x: 100, y: 200, w: 824, h: 400})
.replace """
  <font color="white">
    #{auxiliary}
  </font>
   """
```

What it shows is: `[object Object]`

The data that the server is returning is like this:

```
{
 "message":
   "<p>Help text</p>",
 "result":
   "ok"
}
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$.getJSON` is asynchronous and will just return a deferred, which has no `message` property. You should attach your code to a callback:

```
where = this._current

$.getJSON('/help/', {'scene': where}).done (response) ->
  Crafty.e("HTML")
  .attr({x: 100, y: 200, w: 224, h: 200})
  .replace """
    <font color="white">
      #{response.message}
    </font>
  """
```

Comment: I've copy-pasted it but I still get the `undefined` message

Comment: @Sascuash: Whoops, forgot to rename `response`. Should work now.